# Eloquent save() not working when the value is 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I use eloquent outside of laravel and everything is fine.

BUT I've got a real problem now.

---

I have this code:

```
public function setUserIsGone($userInstance) {

    //$this->database->refresh();

    //$this->setUserIsOffline($userInstance, false);
    //$this->setUserIsNotReady($userInstance, false);
    /*
    if ($this->database->id_user_1 == $userInstance->database->id) {
         $this->database->id_user_1 = 0;
    }

    if ($this->database->id_user_2 == $userInstance->database->id) {
        $this->database->id_user_2 = 0;
    }

    if ($this->database->id_user_3 == $userInstance->database->id) {
        $this->database->id_user_3 = 0;
    }

    if ($this->database->id_user_4 == $userInstance->database->id) {
         $this->database->id_user_4 = 0;
    }
    */
    $this->database->infos = "aaaaaaaaa";    // suscessful updated the record
    $this->database->id_user_2 = 0;

    print_r($this->database->id_user_2 . "\n");  // nonono, nothing changed!!! WTF?
    print_r($this->database->save() . "\n");
    print_r($this->database->id_user_2 . "\n");

    // die('DONE');

    //$this->broadcastRoomUpdates();

}
```

now the problem is.

I have a model instance in `$this->database`, and I want to set the `id_user_2` to 0, but nothing changes after `save()`. I added `$this->database->infos = "aaaaaaa"` which saves, but `id_user_2` is still the old value.

id_user_2 is int(11) in the table

help!!

---

nothing in the model file:

```
<?php

class Room extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

}
```

?>

---

the table:

> CREATE TABLE `cola_rooms` (
>     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `id_user_1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     `id_user_2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     `id_user_3` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     `id_user_4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     `id_match` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     `number` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     `rules` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',
>     `infos` text NOT NULL,
>     `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>     `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

---

please see the codes.
when I run to

```
$this->database->infos = "aaaaaaaaa";
$this->database->id_user_2 = 0;
print_r($this->database->id_user_2 . "\n");
```

now the result of print_r is 0, means right.
then I save() the model and print_r again, yes it's 0.

BUT actually in the mysql table, id_user_2 is still the old value, not 0. but the `infos` is success to change(aaaaaaaa).

I tried to set the id_user_2 to 100, 15, 34, etc... every number works but it really cannot be 0.

```
$this->database->id_user_2 = 10;  // OK
$this->database->id_user_2 = 0;   // NONONO...
```

Comment: Is `id_user_2` defined as a foreign key? And are there any modifiers/setters set up in your model? Show the definition of the model that you're using.

Comment: @aynber no,not a foreign key. no modifiers/setters in model.